# htaccess redirects on apache

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to `.htaccess`.

I am working on a project in which I need to display a different URL after every 15 days.

For e.g. `"mysite.com/S1/folder1"` when I enter this URL in address bar I can see the `index.html` content resides inside the `"folder1"`.

Now I want to display the same `"index.html"` from the same `"folder1"` after 15 days but the URL in the address bar would be something different for e.g. like `"mysite.com/S1/any-other-name"`. Is it possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Shailendra

Answer (score 0):

Try with this .htaccess in mysite.com DocumentRoot folder

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(S1/folder1)/
RewriteRule ^S1/(.*) S1/folder1/
```

If you request something that begins with S1/ it will redirect you to S1/folder1

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, i will try this and let you know soon.